# Shell script - two files source file and destinations file, shell script need to do the following task

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a query while writing the shell script,

For example I have two files

1. `file1.txt`

   ```
   Name=myname
   Country=mycounty
   .
   .
   .
   ```

   So on like 100 lines
2. `file2.txt`

   ```
   Name=othername
   Country=anothercountry
   Occupation=my_occupation
   .
   .
   .
   ```

My question here is I have two files `file1.txt` is destination file and `file2.txt` is source file. What ever the inputs in the destination file must find and replace in the destination file. If it is not matched then add it.

We can use `sed` if we want to edit 2 or 3 lines. For suppose I want to edit 20 lines then it will be difficult.

Please help on this

Comment: What [have you tried so far](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/609841/edit)? It's often easier to build on something you've already tried

Comment: Also, please make the question title more meaningful than "Help of the shell script".

Comment: Can you sort files, or do you need to preserve line order?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I need a script logic, how we can we can do that. If I got the logic then I can make a format

Comment: First need to read the script line by line in the source file which have, then if the line is matched before "=" with the destination file then need to replace in the source file. If not matched, need a add in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `awk` for this, assuming none of the values contained `=`

```
awk -F'=' '
    { h[$1]=$2 }                                          # Save the key/value
    END { for (k in h) { printf "%s=%s\n", k, h[k] } }    # Output all key/value pairs
' file2.txt file1.txt
```

But you could use `sort`

```
sort -t'=' -u -k1,1 file2.txt file1.txt    # Sort by first field discarding duplicates
```

Output (from either)

```
Country=mycounty
Name=myname
Occupation=my_occupation
```